Docker getting stuck at npm install part forever
I am following the exact steps but still it gets stuck when running npm command and I don't know what went wrong here.
Here is the docker code:
FROM node:20-alpine


RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app

USER app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

USER root

RUN chown -R app:app .

USER app


RUN npm install --verbose

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173


CMD npm run dev

Here is the error message I'm getting:

 docker compose up
[+] Building 21.3s (10/12)                                                                              docker:desktop-linux 
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.69kB                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20-alpine                                                   1.8s 
 => [web auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                         0.0s 
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 663B                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [web 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/node:20-alpine@sha256:eb8101caae9ac02229bd64c024919fe3d4504ff7f329da79ca60a04db08  0.0s 
 => [web internal] load build context                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 1.36kB                                                                                     0.0s 
 => CACHED [web 2/7] RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app                                                          0.0s 
 => CACHED [web 3/7] WORKDIR /app                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [web 4/7] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                     0.0s 
 => [web 5/7] RUN chown -R app:app .                                                                                    0.2s 
 => [web 6/7] RUN npm install --verbose                                                                                19.2s 
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-extglob 87ms (cache miss)                                      
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/array-union 90ms (cache miss)                                     
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/merge2 95ms (cache miss)                                          
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/brace-expansion 101ms (cache miss)                                
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-glob 189ms (cache miss)                                      
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/dir-glob 993ms (cache miss)               

I'm beginner to it, I don't know what I did wrong here.

I dont see any errors, i think you will need to increase the log level further. Try npm install --loglevel silly?
